# Tengo problema con la configuración de PHPmailer

Tags: html, phpmailer

Tengo un pequeño problema con la configuración de PHPmailer, cuando hago un envió de una notificación por correo hacia un gmail, recibouna etiqueta `/n` que muestro en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  $saludo = 'hola';
   $contenting=' <p>ijbuasiubasgubisagbusa</p>
    <p>asubvasusabjsaubbujsa</p>
    <p>jbasjbasjbbjasbjs</p>
    <p>jbvasjbsabjbas</p>
    <p>bnasjbasjbjbsa</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>';
```

Ya hice las configuraciones que creí que pudieran ser la solución.

Configuración de PHPmailer

```
$message = "<div style='float: left;width: 100%;'><div style='float:left;width:100%;'><p>".$saludo." </p></div>".$contenting."</div>";


            $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

            $mail->Subject = ''.$asunto.'';
            $mail->setFrom('info@correo.com','nombre');
            $mail->AddBCC('sistemas@correo.com', 'nombre');
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; //Mensajes de debug; 0 = no mostrar (en producción), 1 = de cliente, 2 = de cliente y servidor
            $mail->Debugoutput = 'html'; //Mostrar mensajes (resultados) de depuración(debug) en html


            $word="you'll"; 
            $mail->Body = $message;
            if (!$mail->send()) {
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }else{

                echo "Mensaje Enviado";

            }
```

Comment: Cual es el valor de las variables: $saludo
$contenting podrías mostrar su asignación?.

Comment: Tu problema es que te salen los \n ?

Comment: ese es mi problema, deja edito mi pregunta

Comment: En tu variable $contenting agrega \n al final de cada línea exceptuando la última y vuelve a probar

Comment: No, el problema persiste

Comment: Es extraño, y prueba si te da con \r\n , yo la configuración la veo bien el problema creo que debe ser los saltos de linea que envía el body del mail

Comment: Encontré la solución, al problema plateado